# I need help in ruby for a project

Tags: ruby

For a project I need to create a program that allows my teacher to run it on ruby. When he runs it he should be able to press <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd>, or <kbd>e</kbd> as many times as he wants, as long as he enters one at a time. Those letters represent random items in a store.

- "a" is $0.50 or "3 for a dollar"
- "b" is $1.25
- "c" is $0.75 or "four for two dollars"
- "d" is $1.00
- "e" is $0.69

If he presses any other letter than the five mentioned the program will end, and will spit out the total amount of dollars. I have no clue on how to make the code so every third "a" is a dollar and also for "c", can someone please help me with this.

I have the code running for everything except the "a" and "c" specials.

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
d = 0
e = 0

while true
  letter = gets.chomp

  if letter == "a"
    a += 0.50
  elsif letter == "b"
    b += 1.25
  elsif letter == "c"
    c += 0.75
  elsif letter == "d"
    d += 1.00
  elsif letter == "e"
    e += 0.69
  else
    break
  end
end

print 'Total amount is: '
puts '$%.2f'% ( a + b + c + d + e )
```

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: What is Ruby 6?  Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: You don't seem to think so but grammar and punctuation _are_ important. This stream of consciousness is impenetrable.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow. Would you mind [edit]ing your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Thanks for editing your question. Note that *"3 for a dollar"* and *"every third 'a' is a dollar"* is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the amounts up-front makes it hard to account for the special cases. I would start by *counting* the entered items, maybe using a [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Hash.html), something like:

```
@items = { 'a' => 0, 'b' => 0, 'c' => 0, 'd' => 0, 'e' => 0 }

loop do
  letter = gets.chomp                  # get letter from keyboard
  break unless @items.has_key? letter  # break if letter is not in hash
  @items[letter] += 1                  # increment hash's letter value
end
```

After entering for example "a a a a a b b c", the `@items` hash would look like this:

```
{ 'a' => 5, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 1, 'd' => 0, 'e' => 0 }
```

To calculate the total amount, I would introduce a variable:

```
@total = 0.0
```

For special case "a", we have to determine how many "3 for a dollar" we have and how many regular "a"'s are left. [`Numeric#divmod`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod) returns both values:

```
5.divmod(3) => [1, 2] # i.e. 1 x 3 + 2
```

With our `@items` hash and `@total` variable that becomes:

```
special_count, regular_count = @items['a'].divmod(3)
@total += 1.0 * special_count
@total += 0.5 * regular_count
```

Adding the amount for a non-special case is trivial:

```
@total += 1.25 * @items['b']
```

I guess you can figure out the remaining items yourself.